# Issue with python-socketio catch-all namespaces

Tags: python-socketio

I have the latest version (5.11.0) of python-socketio installed.

I was able to get catch-all events working,

`@sio.on('*')`

`async def handle_event(event, sid, *args):`

I'm following the example/syntax as in the documentation for catch-all namespaces, but couldn't get that to work. Below event handler is not getting invoked.

`@sio.on('my_event', namespace='*')`

`async def my_event(namespace, sid, data):`

Client code:

`await sio.emit('my_event', data='Message from client', namespace='/test')`

If not catch-all namespaces, is there a way to get the namespace from where data was received on the server side? I want to send message back to the client on the same namespace.

Comment: You have omitted important details. How is the client connecting on the `/test` namespace? You can't just emit on any random namespace, a connection has to be made first. And did you configure the server to accept connections for all namespaces? This is not the default.

Comment: Client Connect:                                                                                                               `sio = socketio.AsyncClient()`                                                                                           `@sio.on('connect', namespace='/test')`
`async def on_connect():`
    `await sio.emit('my_event', data='Message from client', namespace='/test')`                  
Server  Connect:      
`for nm in namespaceList:`
    `@sio.on('connect', namespace=nm)`
    `async def connect(sid, environ):`